# How to isolate/use each index value of repeat instances in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, indexof

I'm writing a function that is supposed to take a string value, interpret it as a number in some base (decimal, hex, octal, binary, etc.) and calculate its actual (decimal) value. Here's the code, and below will be the issue I'm struggling with:

```
const Alphabet = {
  BINARY:        '01',
  OCTAL:         '01234567',
  DECIMAL:       '0123456789',
  HEXA_DECIMAL:  '0123456789abcdef',
  ALPHA_LOWER:   'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
  ALPHA_UPPER:   'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  ALPHA:         'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  ALPHA_NUMERIC: '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
}

function getValue(num, fromBase) {
    const fblen = fromBase.length;
    const digits = num.toString().split('');
  const digitAmt = digits.map(function(digit) {
    return fromBase.indexOf(digit) * (fblen**((digits.length - 1) - digits.indexOf(digit)));
  });
  return digitAmt.reduce(function(n, m) {
    return n + m;
  });
}

console.log(getValue('fff', Alphabet.HEXA_DECIMAL))
```

So what is meant to happen is I pass a `num` (for example, `'abc'`), and the base of the number (we'll use `HEXA_DECIMAL`).  The base-10 equivalent of the hex number `'abc'` would be `2748`:

```
162(10) + 161(11) + 160(12) = 2560 + 176 + 12 = 2748
```

and sure enough, that's what the function will produce. However, if I input `'fff'`, I hit a snag. I get:

```
162(15) + 162(15) + 162(15) = 3840 + 3840 + 3840 = 11520
```

rather than the expected:

```
162(15) + 161(15) + 160(15) = 3840 + 240 + 15 = 4095
```

I realized where the problem is coming from: the variable `digits.indexOf(digit)` gets caught because `.indexOf()` only returns the index of the first instance. Now I'm stuck figuring out how to get the correct index number, which will calculate the correct exponent and make the function work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `.map()` passes index to callback

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

So if you modify your code like below, it should work

```
const digitAmt = digits.map(function(digit, index) {
    return fromBase.indexOf(digit) * (fblen ** ((digits.length - 1) - index));
  });
```